# Filter close-vote queue by specific offtopic reason

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

Please add possibility to check any set of offtopic reason. They are very different to group.

For example I'd review general offtopic/custom offtopic/belongs to other site but I don't like  reviewing "please post SSCCE" and "minimal understanding reasons.